# How to specify criteria for node-red-node-email in Node-RED

Tags: node-red

I want to search for specific emails in my inbox using the `node-red-node-email` node in Node-RED.

The help says I should specify conditions in `msg.criteria`:

> Uses the `node-imap` module - see that page for information on the `msg.criteria` format if needed.

The referenced doc page explains *what* to put there but not *how* to do it.

As `node-red-node-email` node is an originating (?) node, no payload (i.e. `msg` object) is passed to it. There's no way to specify a different object (e.g., a `flow.` variable) for the criteria either.

How can I specify `msg.criteria` (or more generally, how can I specify search criteria) so that `node-red-node-email` uses it?

[image: Node-RED email node msg.criteria]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the "Get Mail" entry at the top of the config from "automatically" to "when triggered" and the email node will gain an input port.

You can then use this to trigger the node to check for new mail and add the `msg.criteria`

Comment: Check your logs, but having looked at the code it will only use `msg.criteria` and no other `msg` properties. Also make sure you have the  latest version of node-red-nodes-email installed.

Comment: This is not the place to debug this. Post to the Node-RED Discord group (link on the bottom of the homepage)

Comment: Due to a bug in `node-red-node-email` 1.7.6, the flow was breaking with an `Error: Timed out while connecting to server` message. Version 1.7.7 fixed that.